# Arm g++ cross compiler error

Tags: c++, arm, g++, ubuntu-14.04, cross-compiling

I am getting an error while trying to build a binary using arm cross compiler on Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

Below is the command I used:

```
arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-g++ --sysroot=/home/ubuntu/das_toolchain/sysroots/aarch64-oe-linux/ --verbose sample.cpp
```

The compiler is (the result of the command "which arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-g++"):

```
/home/ubuntu/das_toolchain/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-g++
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-g++
Target: arm-oe-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: /home/builduser/workspace/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work-shared/gcc-4.9.3-r0/gcc-4.9.3/configure --build=x86_64-linux --host=x86_64-oesdk-linux --target=arm-oe-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr --exec_prefix=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr --bindir=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi --sbindir=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi --libexecdir=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi --datadir=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/share --sysconfdir=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/etc --sharedstatedir=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/com --localstatedir=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/var --libdir=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/lib/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi --includedir=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/include --oldincludedir=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/include --infodir=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/share/man --disable-silent-rules --disable-dependency-tracking --with-libtool-sysroot=/home/builduser/workspace/poky/build/tmp-glibc/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-oesdk-linux --with-gnu-ld --enable-shared --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-threads=posix --enable-multilib --enable-c99 --enable-long-long --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-pch --program-prefix=arm-oe-linux-gnueabi- --without-local-prefix --enable-target-optspace --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-bootstrap --disable-libmudflap --with-system-zlib --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-linker-build-id --with-ppl=no --with-cloog=no --enable-checking=release --enable-cheaders=c_global --with-gxx-include-dir=/not/exist/usr/include/c++/4.9.3 --with-build-time-tools=/home/builduser/workspace/poky/build/tmp-glibc/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/bin --with-sysroot=/not/exist --with-build-sysroot=/home/builduser/workspace/poky/build/tmp-glibc/sysroots/lib32-apq8053 --enable-poison-system-directories --with-mpfr=/home/builduser/workspace/poky/build/tmp-glibc/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-oesdk-linux --with-mpc=/home/builduser/workspace/poky/build/tmp-glibc/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-oesdk-linux --enable-nls --with-arch=armv7-a
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='--sysroot=/home/ubuntu/das_toolchain/sysroots/aarch64-oe-linux/' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-march=armv7-a' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
cc1plus -quiet -v -isysroot /home/ubuntu/das_toolchain/sysroots/aarch64-oe-linux/ -D_GNU_SOURCE sample.cpp -quiet -dumpbase sample.cpp -march=armv7-a -mtls-dialect=gnu -auxbase sample -version -o /tmp/cc7ApGfu.s
arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

The version of my cross g++ compiler is:

```
$ arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-g++ --version
arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-g++ (GCC) 4.9.3
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I cannot wrap my head around this error. Please help out here.

Comment: The error sounds clear to me. There's a file 'cc1plus' searched and not found. Have you searched for this file? Do you have this file? Maybe it's just a path issue.

Comment: I have this file, yes. When I try to add the location of that file in PATH env variable, then it starts to complain about all c++ specific files and symbols, e.g. it complains that it cannot find <iostream> header.